# Probability of Guessing 3 out of 4 numbers over 10000 numbers

Tags: probability

There are 10,000 numbers to be picked say 0000-9999.
Game pick 4 numbers. (no repeat)
Player pick 3 numbers to guess what are the number the game had picked. (no repeat)

What are the chance of player picking all 3 numbers correctly out of the 4 that the game picked? numbers can be in any order.

Example
Game: 0001, 1111, 2222, 4111
Player: 4111, 0001, 1111

Player got 3 out 4. What is the probability of this happening?

Edit: To show where I'm at.

Chance to match (n = total numbers in the pool)

1st number is (1/n) = 1/10000

2nd number is (1/n-1) = 1/9999

3rd number is (1/n-2) = 1/9998

chance of matching 3 numbers = 1/999,700,020,000 with a factorial of 6 for possible combination of 3 numbers.
= 166,616,670,000

but since the game will pick 4 number instead of 3, I'm not sure how to calculate this.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Think about the following things: what is the probability that the first number is correctly picked? How does this effect the following number? Is one number taken out of the group of 10.000 numbers, or doesnt that have any influence? (in this case yes) How can you arrange the number picking?  These are the things you should be thinking about. Please show your work, then we know at which question you have some problems

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the game selects four numbers, the probability of successfully picking one of them on the first try is $4/1000$.  If the player is successful on the first try, the probability of picking one of the remaining three numbers the game selected from the remaining $999$ numbers is $3/999$.  If the player is successful on each of the first two tries, the probability of picking one of the remaining two numbers the game selected from the remaining $998$ numbers is $2/998$.  Multiplying these probabilities yields the probability that the player wins the game, which is
$$\Pr(\text{player wins}) = \frac{4}{1000} \cdot \frac{3}{999} \cdot \frac{2}{998}$$
Alternatively, if you are familiar with combinations, the player must choose three of the four numbers the game selects while selecting three of the $1000$ available numbers, which is
$$\Pr(\text{player wins}) = \frac{\dbinom{4}{3}}{\dbinom{1000}{3}}$$